# R- How many times do values from one column of a dataframe appear in others? (preferably without the use of for loop)

Tags: r, data.table

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now, so I hope someone can help me find a more time efficient solution.
So, I have a dataframe of ID's like this:

```
IDinsurer<-c(rep(11,3),rep(12,2),rep(11,2),rep(13,2),11)
ClaimFileNum<-c(rep('AA',3),rep('BB',2),rep('CC',2),rep('DD',2),'EE')
IDdriver<-c(rep(11,3),rep(12,2),rep(21,2),rep(13,2),11)
IDclaimant<-c(31,11,32,12,33,11,34,13,11,11)
IDclaimdriver<-c(41,11,32,12,11,21,34,13,12,11)
dt<-data.frame(ClaimFileNum,IDinsurer,IDdriver,IDclaimant,IDclaimdriver)

   ClaimFileNum IDinsurer IDdriver IDclaimant IDclaimdriver
1            AA        11       11         31            41
2            AA        11       11         11            11
3            AA        11       11         32            32
4            BB        12       12         12            12
5            BB        12       12         33            11
6            CC        11       21         11            21
7            CC        11       21         34            34
8            DD        13       13         13            13
9            DD        13       13         11            12
10           EE        11       11         11            11
```

What I'd like to do is to count the number of different claim files (ClaimFileNum) the individual IDinsurer has appeared on in other roles ( i.e. not as an insurer). So for each IDinsurer I only want the count of claim files, where his ID appeared in either IDdriver, IDclaimant or IDclaimdriver while at the same time he isn't the IDinsurer of the given claimfile. For example, IDinsurer==11 appeared with all ClaimFileNums, but only on "BB" and "DD" he wasn't also the IDinsurer meaning I'd want my program to return 2.
So this is how I'd like my final data frame to look like:

```
   ClaimFileNum IDinsurer IDdriver IDclaimant IDclaimdriver N
1            AA        11       11         31            41 2
2            AA        11       11         11            11 2
3            AA        11       11         32            32 2
4            BB        12       12         12            12 1
5            BB        12       12         33            11 1
6            CC        11       21         11            21 2
7            CC        11       21         34            34 2
8            DD        13       13         13            13 0
9            DD        13       13         11            12 0
10           AA        11       11         11            11 2
```

So this is what I was able to come up with so far:

1) 
For each of the three other roles (IDdriver, IDclaimant, IDclaimdriver) I individually calculated a new column with numbers revealing how many claim files the specific ID's appeared on IN THAT ROLE ONLY, excluding the cases of claim files, where they were also the insurers (for IDclaimdriver however it made more sense to exclude the cases where the ID matched either IDclaimant or IDdriver instead) . This is the code for the IDdriver counts:

```
count.duplicates <- function(dt){                                 #removing duplicated columns and adding a column with the frequency of duplications
  x <- do.call('paste', c(dt[,c("ClaimFileNum","IDdriver")], sep = '\r'))
  ox <- order(x)
  rl <- rle(x[ox])
  cbind(dt[ox[cumsum(rl$lengths)],,drop=FALSE],count = rl$lengths)

}
dt<-count.duplicates(dt)
dt<-data.table(dt)
dt[,same:=ifelse(dt$IDinsurer==dt$IDdriver,0,1)]
dt[,N_IDdriver:=sum(same,na.rm = T),by=list(IDdriver)]
dt[,same:=NULL]

setorder(dt,ClaimFileNum)
dt<-expandRows(dt,"count")
dt<-as.data.frame(dt)
```

And this is the output for my example after all three counts:

```
       ClaimFileNum IDinsurer IDdriver IDclaimant IDclaimdriver N_IDdriver N_IDclaimant N_IDclaimdriver
1            AA        11       11         31            41          0            1               1
2            AA        11       11         11            11          0            1               1
3            AA        11       11         32            32          0            1               0
4            BB        12       12         12            12          0            0               1
5            BB        12       12         33            11          0            1               1
6            CC        11       21         11            21          1            1               0
7            CC        11       21         34            34          1            1               0
8            DD        13       13         13            13          0            0               0
9            DD        13       13         11            12          0            1               1
10           EE        11       11         11            11          0            1               1
```

2) I now used a for loop over an entire IDinsurer column first to check if the insurerID[i] has appeared in any of the other three roles ID's using match function. If the match was found I simply added the count from the corresponding N_ column to the overall count.
Here is my for loop:

```
total<-length(dt$IDinsurer)
for(i in 1:total) {
  j<-match(dt$IDinsurer[i],dt$IDdriver,nomatch=0);
  k<-match(dt$IDinsurer[i],dt$IDclaimant,nomatch=0);
  l<-match(dt$IDinsurer[i],dt$IDclaimdriver,nomatch=0);
  dt$N[i]<-ifelse(j==0,0,N_IDdriver[j])+ifelse(k==0,0,N_IDclaimant[k])+ifelse(l==0,0,N_IDclaimdriver[l]);
}
```

Now while this approach gives me all the information I need, it's unfortunately incredibly sluggish, especially on a dataset with over 2 million cases like the one I'll have to work with. I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution and I've been trying to figure out how to do it with some more efficient tools (like data.table) but I just can't get the grasp of it.

**EDIT:** I decided to try both of the answers to my question on my example and compare them with my attempt so here are the calculation times:
Thom Quinn's for loop: 0.15sec,
my for loop: 0.25 sec,
bounyball's approach: 0.35 sec.

Using my loop on a 1,042,000 row dataset took just under 10 hours.

Comment: How many _unique_  (a) "ClaimFileNum"s, (b) IDs and, (c) roles does your data contain?

Comment: @alexis_laz The dataset available to me at the moment has 1,042,000 rows, 311000 unique insurer ID's, same amount of roles as in my example (for the moment, ther emight be six in a worst case scenario) and 435000 unique ClaimFileNum's.

Comment: You could try finding your way through tabulating; though you'll need to be careful on memory constraints. A quick idea is `idIns = unique(dt$IDinsurer); tabs = lapply(dt[-1], function(x) table(dt[[1]], factor(x, idIns))); colSums(with(tabs, (!IDinsurer) & (IDdriver | IDclaimant | IDclaimdriver)))` and, then, merge that as your wanted column. Probably instead of `lapply`, you might try a simple loop of iterative tabulations and accumulate with "|" along the way to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

Match is notoriously slow and not needed in this case. In fact, you already solved the problem in English, you need just need to translate it to computer lingo!

> So for each IDinsurer I only want the count of claim files, where his ID appeared in either IDdriver, IDclaimant or IDclaimdriver while at the same time he isn't the IDinsurer of the given claimfile

So, let's do just that. In pseudo-code:

```
for each unique IDinsurer:
  count when IDdriver OR IDclaimant OR IDclaimdriver AND NOT IDinsurer
```

In R, this is:

```
for(i in unique(dt$IDinsurer)){
  index <- dt$IDinsurer != i & (dt$IDdriver == i | dt$IDclaimant == i | dt$IDclaimdriver == i)
  dt[dt$IDinsurer == i, "N"] <- sum(index)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to `apply` to `do.call` to `merge`.
We first **split** the data by unique `ID`. Then, we look at the data by excluding any rows where the `ID` equals the `IDInsurer`. Within that data set, we look for entries where any of the other `ID`'s are equal to the `ID` we're working with. Then we combine the data and fold it up using `merge`.

```
res.df <- 
  do.call('rbind.data.frame',
     lapply(unique(dt$IDinsurer), function(x) 
  c(
    x, sum(apply(dt[dt$IDinsurer != x, 3:5] == x, 1, function(y) any(y)))
   )
  )
)

names(res.df) <- c('ID', 'Count')

merge(dt, res.df, by.x = 'IDinsurer', by.y = 'ID')

   IDinsurer ClaimFileNum IDdriver IDclaimant IDclaimdriver Count
1         11           AA       11         31            41     2
2         11           AA       11         11            11     2
3         11           AA       11         32            32     2
4         11           CC       21         11            21     2
5         11           CC       21         34            34     2
6         11           EE       11         11            11     2
7         12           BB       12         12            12     1
8         12           BB       12         33            11     1
9         13           DD       13         13            13     0
10        13           DD       13         11            12     0
```

Comment: I don't know, to me this double apply loop doesn't look too appealing for larger dataset with million+ rows and more than half a million unique insurers... Even on a such a small dataset it took a third more time than my initial for loop. I'll try it on a whole dataset with a pbapply, and report back the estimated time.